# Proving some identities about the time derivative of the k-th covariant derivatives of scalar curvature under normalized Ricci flow on surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

I'm trying to prove the following identities (under the normalized Ricci flow on surfaces, on which $\partial_t g = (r-R)g$ holds true, where $r$ denotes the average scalar curvature and has the same sign as the Euler characteristic):

> $$
> \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\nabla^{k} R\right)=\Delta \nabla^{k} R-r\left(\nabla^{k} R\right)+\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor k / 2\rfloor}\left(\nabla^{j} R\right) \otimes_{g}\left(\nabla^{k-j} R\right)
> $$
>
> $$
> \begin{array}{l}
> \frac{\partial}{\partial t}(|\nabla^k R |^2) =\Delta\left|\nabla^{k} R\right|^{2}-2\left|\nabla^{k+1} R\right|^{2}-(k+2) r\left|\nabla^{k} R\right|^{2} 
> +\left(\nabla^{k} R\right) \otimes_{g}\left[\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor k / 2\rfloor}\left(\nabla^{j} R\right) \otimes_{g}\left(\nabla^{k-j} R\right)\right]
> \end{array}
> $$

where by $A \otimes_g B$ we refer to any tensor field which is a finite linear combination of contractions and metric contractions of the tensor product $A \otimes B$. Now, I've already proven that the following hold:

> $$\partial_{t} \nabla R=\Delta \nabla R+\frac{3}{2} R \nabla R-r \nabla R$$
> $$
> \nabla^{n} \Delta R-\Delta \nabla^{n} R=\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor n / 2\rfloor}\left(\nabla^{j} R\right) \otimes_{g(t)}\left(\nabla^{n-j} R\right)
> $$
> $$
> \begin{array}{c}
> \nabla^{n} R^{2}=\displaystyle{\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor n / 2\rfloor}\left(\nabla^{j} R\right) \otimes_{g(t)}\left(\nabla^{n-j} R\right) }\\
> \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \Gamma\right) \otimes_{g(t)}\left(\nabla^{j} R\right)=(\nabla R) \otimes_{g(t)}\left(\nabla^{j} R\right)
> \end{array}
> $$
> $$
> \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\nabla_{k_{1}} \nabla_{k_{2}} \ldots \nabla_{k_{n}} R\right)=\nabla_{k_{1}}\left\{\partial_t \nabla_{k_{2}} \ldots \nabla_{k_{n}} R\right\}-\sum_{l=2}^{n}\left(\partial_{t} \Gamma_{k_{1} k_{l}}^{m}\right) \nabla_{k_{2}} \ldots \nabla_{k_{l-1}} \nabla_{m} \ldots \nabla_{k_{n}} R
> $$

So, to prove the first formula for the evolution of $\nabla^k R$, I used recursive applications of this last identity just above, but I'd like someone to check my work. I noticed there would be terms of the form:

\begin{align*}
\nabla_{k_1} \cdots \nabla_{k_{n-1}}(\partial_t \nabla_{k_n} R) &= \nabla_{k_1} \cdots \nabla_{k_{n-1}}(\Delta \nabla_{k_n}R + \frac{3}{2} R \nabla_{k_n} R - r \nabla_{k_n R}) \\
&= \nabla_{k_1} \cdots \nabla_{k_{n-1}} ( \nabla_{k_n} \Delta R + \Sigma + \frac{3}{2} R \nabla_{k_n} R - r \nabla_{k_n R} )\\
&=\nabla^k \Delta R + \Sigma - r(\nabla^{k} R) \\
&=\Delta \nabla^k R + \Sigma - r(\nabla^k R)
\end{align*}

where by $\Sigma$ I'm denoting $\displaystyle{\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor k / 2\rfloor}\left(\nabla^{j} R\right) \otimes_{g}\left(\nabla^{k-j} R\right)}$ to avoid taking up too much space. The remaining terms are of the form:

$$
\left(\partial_{t} \Gamma\right) \otimes \nabla^{k-1} R=\nabla R \otimes \nabla^{k-1} R=\Sigma
$$

and so we have proved the first identity. But I didn't manage to prove the second one. We have:

$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left|\nabla^{k} R\right|^{2} &=  \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(g^{i_1 p_1} \cdots g^{i_k p_k} \nabla_{i_1} \cdots \nabla_{i_k} R \nabla_{p_1} \cdots \nabla_{p_k} R\right) \\
&=(R-r)k \|\nabla^k R \|^2 + 2 \langle \nabla^k R, \partial_t(\nabla^k R) \rangle
\end{aligned}
$$

and since

\begin{align*}
2 \langle \nabla^k R, \partial_t(\nabla^k R) \rangle &= 2 \langle \nabla^k R, \Delta \nabla^k R + \Sigma - r \nabla^k R \rangle \\
&=2 \langle \nabla^k R, \Delta \nabla^k R \rangle + 2 \langle \nabla^k R, \Sigma \rangle - 2r \|\nabla^k R\|^2
\end{align*}

We're then left to prove that:

$$2 \langle \nabla^k R, \Delta \nabla^k R \rangle = -kR \|\nabla^k R\|^2 + \Delta \|\nabla^k R\|^2 - 2 \|\nabla^{k+1} R\|^2$$

but I've been stuck on this one for a while. I'd really appreciate some help on this! Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know if my comment would be relevant, but I think MathOverflow would be a more relevant place to ask this because, regarding the high level of the question

Comment: @DIdier_ thank you for your comment (it was indeed relevant!), I wasn't sure if I should post it to MathOverflow but I have done so now.